# Making and loading cubemaps in modern DirectX (11, post Windows 8.1)

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-11

I have been trying to figure out how to create and use cube maps for my Direct3D 11 program.

I have been led to believe that if I export my 6 images to a DDS file, I can simply load that one file using `CreateDDSTextureFromFile(_device, inName, (ID3D11Resource**)&_texture, &_shaderResourceView)`. However I cannot find the tool that seems like it's supposed to be used for compiling the textures into DDS: dxtex.exe. In theory, it ships with the DirectX SDK, which has become defunct since Windows 8.1 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx). I have searched my hard drive and it does not exist (so presumably wasn't installed alongside Visual Studio -- I have 2013 and 2015; I'm running Windows 10, upgraded from 8.1).

There is also an Nvidia plugin for Photoshop which hasn't been updated in 3 years and crashes my copy of Photoshop when I try to run it (CC 2015). There are rumors of an AMD tool, but I read that it's not been supported for a while, like the Nvidia tool.

I even saw this post from a couple years back where they are simply loading up each texture individually (but for which it seems you are expected to use an outside library, as the `CreateXXXTextureFromFile(...)` functions expect to assign a resource view, which I don't need until I've set up the array of texture data as a single cube map.

My question is this: how is someone intended to save out and load up cube maps these days? There doesn't appear to be any route that seems intentional so much as incidental.

I would prefer to load a single texture if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the legacy DirectX SDK (June 2010) to get the old DXTex tool. Keep in mind that there are [known issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/24/10246203.aspx) with installing the legacy DirectX SDK, that some of the legacy DirectX SDK is not compatible with [DirectX 11.1 or later runtimes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/14/directx-11-1-and-windows-7.aspx), and that the DXTex tool does not support all DXGI formats--for details see [The DDS File Format Lives](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/02/05/the-dds-file-format-lives.aspx).

The [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) library project includes a command-line tool [texassemble](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texassemble) which you can use to build up complex arrays, cubemaps, and volume maps from individual image files into a DDS. You can then process that DDS into other formats (like block compressing it to a BC format) using the [texconv](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texconv) command-line tool.

> Making a new version of DXTex using DirectXTex is a [backlog item](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/issues/2).

You can use the [DDSTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DDSTextureLoader) code to create a resource at runtime from your complex DDS file.

Comment: I'm having good luck using texassemble. For the sake of completion, I found [this page](http://www.digitalrune.com/Documentation/html/82aae839-9dee-4d18-b87b-85da2b547f7f.htm) describing the order which texture arguments should be given to correctly assemble your skybox. `(+X, -X, +Y, -Y, +Z, -Z)`

Comment: [This page](https://directxtex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Texassemble&referringTitle=Texconv) seems to be the official documentation with the same information, albeit not quite so direct.

Comment: I maintain both the CodePlex and GitHub versions of DirectXTex for now, but the GitHub versions are the preferred ones including the docs as that's where I'm focusing future content.